# Resharper adds blank lines on code format

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-2017, resharper, text-editor

Visual Studio has suddenly, out the blue, started adding blank lines between lines of code for Javascript/Typescript files only.  Within the same copy of VS I can edit .cs files without any issue.

This happens on format (i.e. add a closing brace `}`, paste etc) but weirdly doesnt happen on CTRL+K,D.

Its driving me insane can someone tell me how to turn it off please :)

**Edit 1** I have resharper installed if that makes any difference

**Edit 2** If I continually remove and put the final brace of a function back in it continually adds new lines between every line of code

**Edit 3** If I disable resharper it doesnt happen, so its a Resharper issue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same thing happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your ReSharper settings for Javascript and Typescript. Chances are someone or something has changed the options for the number of blank lines after certain things.

[image: ReSharper settings dialog focused on Line Breaks]